# postfix dsn=2.5.0 won't send notification

Tags: postfix, smtp, dsn

I'm facing a problem with Postfix. I've configured it to send notifications if message delivered, bounced, deferred. I recieve notifications, but some times in logs I get record like this:

```
1765BA8A0: to=<info@example.com>, relay=mx5.mail.icloud.com[17.158.8.111]:25, delay=4.7, delays=0.05/0.01/0.34/4.3, dsn=2.5.0, status=sent (250 2.5.0 Ok.)
```

And there is no notification from my postfix either relay server. According to `status=send` the message was delivered, but it's critical for me to receive notification email. Why do I have no notification?

Comment: You'll have to ask Apple. We have no way of knowing why Apple is not delivering your mail to you.

Comment: Despite I get this issue only with Apple, I don't think that they can help me, I guess there is some way to configure Postfix to parse dsn=2.5.0 code as delivered

Comment: What are you talking about? That code _means_ that your mail was delivered successfully.

Comment: Please at least show your config to see what you actually configured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. Postfix is configured to send delivery notifications in case when relay server does not support DSN, otherwise it would consider the relay server to send it. In my case iCloud MX servers replys that they provide DSN service so postfix do nothing in that way, and the problem was that iCloud servers acted in the same way.

So I decided to discard DSN keyword in EHLO returned by iCloud servers, to do this I added following row in my postfix config

```
smtp_discard_ehlo_keyword_address_maps = cidr:/etc/postfix/esmtp_access
```

and create file with list of subnets that iCloud uses to send emails:

```
# File /etc/postfix/esmtp_access
17.142.0.0/16          dsn
17.158.0.0/16          dsn
17.178.0.0/16          dsn
17.172.0.0/16          dsn
17.151.0.0/16          dsn
17.133.0.0/16          dsn
```

so now postfix does not recieve DSN keyword and send DSN notification by itself